# Проверочное слово к слову «окрестность»

Tags: орфография, фонетика

В слове *окрестность* есть непроизносимая согласная *т*.
Какое будет проверочное слово?

Если верить Викисловарю, корень здесь *окрест-*. Каким словом показать, что в корне есть *т*, чтобы она произносилась?

Comment: Это невозможно понять. Это надо запомнить. :)

Comment: В соответствии с последними нормативами русского языка корнем будет считаться все же `крест`, а `o-` в данном случае выступит приставкой.

Comment: Лучше искать тут в украинском языке, там что-то подобное помнится насчет указания направлений.
Так, например, оКОЛО - это то же что и воКРУГ. а оКРЕСТность указывает на четыре стороны света, ка ки переКРЕСТок.

Comment: @Sugar Хотелось бы увидеть ссылку на источник, в котором говорится об этих последних нормативах.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Окрест** - не только корень, но и устаревшее слово, синоним слова **вокруг**.

Толковый словарь Ушакова:

> ОКРЕ́СТ (книжн. поэт. устар.). 1. предлог с род. Вокруг, по соседству от чего-нибудь. «Окрест него дремучий бор.» Жуковский. 2. нареч. Вокруг, по близости, по соседству. «Окрест ни один не мерцает маяк.» А.Блок.

Этимологически это слово заимствовано из старо-славянского (производное от слова *крест*) и буквально означало "местность вокруг креста":

> ОКРЕСТ. Заимств. из ст.-сл. яз., где оно является преф. производным от крьстъ (см. крест). Буквально — "местность вокруг креста, окрестность". Ср. вокруг. ([Этимологический словарь](http://slovari.yandex.ru/~%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82/))

Comment: Я сомневался, а сам не нашел подробностей происхождения. Слово «окрест» не употребляется, и кажется, что такого слова нет. Но это всё объясняет. Спасибо!

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov "окрест" в ruscorpora сколько угодно встречается

Answer (score 4):

Помимо слова "окрест" можно [проверить слово "окрестность"](http://russkiiyazyk.ru/orfografiya/pravopisanie/proverochnoe-slovo-k-slovu-okrestnost.html) словами "крест", "перекресток", "крестильный".